# Corda webserver produces exception "User not authorized to perform RPC call nodeInfo with target"

Tags: rpc, corda

I am trying to restrict a node to perform certain flow,

For Example, I have two flows FlowOne and FlowTwo.

For PartyA, I want to give permission for FlowOne,

For PartyB permission for FlowTwo.

Permission to the rpc calls should be there also.

Here is my `rpcUsers` configuration

```
PartyA: rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["StartFlow.net.corda.mortgage.msr.flows.FlowOne","InvokeRpc.startFlow"]]]

PartyB: rpcUsers = [[ user: "user2", "password": "test", "permissions": ["StartFlow.net.corda.mortgage.msr.flows.FlowTwo","InvokeRpc.startFlow"]]]
```

I am not sure What I am missing in the permissions. Any suggestions are always welcome

Answer (score 1):

At start-up, the Corda webserver makes an RPC call to retrieve the `NodeInfo` of the node it is connecting to. It needs to explicitly be given the permission to make this call.

You do this by giving the RPC user:

- The `InvokeRpc.nodeInfo` permission (you give an RPC user the permission to perform a given RPC operation by adding a permission of the form `InvokeRpc.[RPC method name]`)
- The `ALL` permission (this gives the RPC user all permissions)

If you're starting the nodes via `deployNodes`, you add the permission as follows:

```
rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["InvokeRpc.nodeInfo"]]]
```

Or:

```
rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
```

If you're starting the nodes via the node driver (as seen here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example/NodeDriver.kt), you add the permission as follows:

```
val user = User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("InvokeRpc.nodeInfo"))
```

Or:

```
val user = User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("ALL"))
```